# ASP.NET How to use Counter with '<%=

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make a multiple upload, iam using some script from this forum.
the scripts is perfectly works, but when i merge it with my project.
javascript can't get the value of my element.
i found out the problem is because i have many ID PANEL in the page, i need to change to `getElementByID('<%="FileUpdate.ClientID%>').value` (the original : `getElementByID("FileUpdate").value`)

THE PROBLEM IS :
I have to use counter, ex: `getElementByID('<%="txtFileUpdate' + counter + '%>').value` but it FAIL.
the error says "too many characters in character literal" pointing to that line.

Please someone help, is there any solution for this problem ?

Here is the script

**-----> Error " to many characters in character literal"**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    var counter = 1;

    function AddFileUpload() {
        if (counter < 5) {
            counter++;
            var div = document.createElement('DIV');
            div.innerHTML = '<input id="FileUpload' + counter + '" name = "file' + counter +
         '" type="file" />' +
          '<input id="Button' + counter + '" type="button" ' +
          'value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveFileUpload(this)" />';
            document.getElementById("FileUploadContainers").appendChild(div);
        }
        else {
            alert("Cannot attach more than 5 file");
        }
    }

    function GetFile() {
        var temp;
        var error = "";
        var stringx = "";
        var exCounter = 1 ;
        for (exCounter; exCounter <= counter; exCounter++) {
     -----> stringx = document.getElementById('<%=FileUpload'+exCounter+'.ClientID%>').value;    
                if (stringx != "")
                temp += stringx + "#;";
            else 
                error += exCounter + ", ";                            
        }
        if (error != "") {
            alert("Field " + error + " Still Empty");
            return;
        }
            document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value = temp;            
    }
```

Comment: what does it mean - "I have to use counter"? do you have some ListView or Repeater for you FileUpload elements. please show the code.

Comment: That won't work.  The reason is that the code between `<%...%>` is executed on the server, but the "exCounter" is javascript executed on the client.  This is just gibberish to asp.net

Comment: You're going to have to completely change how you do this.  You might consider using jQuery to get an array of input type file, then using the counter as an index into that array

Comment: @Mystere Man : Thanks for your advice, could u give some link reference about using jquery related to this problem.

Comment: You have a very specific problem, there's not going to be any references out there, you will have to figure it out.

Comment: So i must completely change the code. /sad/ it feels so close..
Is there another way to make a multiple upload dynamicaly in aspx page that have many panel ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getElementByID('FileUpdate<%=counter%>').value
```

or

```
getElementByID('<%=txtFileUpdate + counter.ToString()%>').value
```

Comment: @ Andrew Cooper : Still Error Sir, The name 'Counter' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @ Andrew Cooper :
1. The name 'FileUploadContainer' does not exist in the current context
2. The name 'Counter' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You'll need to post some more code to show the context.  Where is `counter` declared?